# What do I call a person who I have helped?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What do I call a person who I have helped? I help others, what should I call them or when I'm writing, how should I mention them?

Comment: My beneficiaries?

Comment: Hi @user3044126 and welcome to ELU.  Can you please tell us what sort of help you give to people and if this on a voluntary basis? We need more information to help us see if we can answer your question. Another Stack Exchange site you might find useful is: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Internship, feels like volunteering, translate to spanish the local events for the spanish community

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***[beneficiary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficiary)*** is appropriate?

> one that benefits from something